# Unable to see the created database in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I created a database named stock_analysis and worked a few things in this database. On the next day, I open the pgAdmin 4 to continue the work - However, I can not see the stock_analysis database in the browser at the left pane anymore.
[image]
But, when I check the object with the query below:

```
SELECT datname FROM pg_database
```

The stock_analysis is still there in the result. How can I make the database visible and access it ?

Kind regards,
Ken Masters

Comment: Refresh the pgAdmin view? Or perhaps you are connected to the wrong cluster.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe - I tried to refresh several times but it does not show up. The database and server are on my local machine, I am not sure why this happens - At the first time I created it, the stock_analysis did show up on the browser pane.